# Is an attempt to modify a const_cast-ed, but dynamically allocated constant object still undefined behavior?

Tags: c++, compiler-optimization, heap-memory, undefined-behavior, const-cast

For example:

```
const int* pc = new const int(3);     // note the const
      int* p  = const_cast<int*>(pc);

*p = 4; // undefined behavior?
```

In particular, can the compiler ever optimize away the **heap**-allocated `*pc`?

If not, does an attempt to modify `*pc` via `p` still constitute undefined behavior - and if so, why?

Comment: It's an interesting question but why would you do that?

Comment: related - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22798558/is-it-legal-to-modify-an-object-created-with-new-through-a-const-pointer

Comment: const_cast should only be used for interfacing with code that is const-incorrect, for example a function that doesn't modify a string but still takes a char* instead of const char*.
Any other kind of use where you modify the object is undefined behavior

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes and yes. As to why - because you're modifying a `const` object.

And good point about the `const` after `new` - without it, the code would be legal.

Answer (score 3):

`const_cast` from `const` to non-`const` is only safe if the original pointer was non-`const`.

If the original pointer is `const` (as is the case in your example) then the behaviour is undefined.

If you had written

`const int* pc = new int(3);`

then you *could* cast away the `const`-ness of `pc`.